# (Microsoft Word) How to stop styles opening in a box?

Tags: formatting, microsoft, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I'm trying to make some text be in the style of Header 1, Header 2, Header 3, etc

When I change the style of text, it opens up in this box instead of staying normal text that is in line with the rest of the text. I don't understand why, I've never seen this before. It comes with an arrow that lets you move it anywhere on the page. You can see the broken line around the text. How do I make it stay normal and not go in a box?[image]

Comment: Does this happen with all heading styles (1, 2, 3, ...).? Does it happen with other styles? Also, when you click on the border, does a new "Format" tab pop up?

Comment: Consider using and modifying the built-in heading styles. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/10HeadingStyles.htm. Can you save a sample document with the problem on DropBox or OneDrive and edit your question to include a link to the document?